# Is the keyboard on the 15" Mac Book Pro with Retina display different than others in size?

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro, accessories

I just got a new 15" Retina MacBook Pro (rMBP) for a friend and looking for a good keyboard guard/ cover. I know shopping questions are off topic, but I'm wondering if the sizing is something that differers between Mac models.

I have [Moshi ClearGuard](http://store.apple.com/us/product/TV901LL/A/moshi-clearguard-keyboard-protector-for-aluminum-macbook-and-macbook-pro) for my 2009 15" MBP. Would that work for the rMBP or do I need to look for something specific to Retina models?

Comment: Hardware shopping questions are discouraged quite strongly - even when they get to subjective things like I need it to be black, the answers tend to be trivial and well covered by internet shopping sites. I've edited this to keep the objective question of whether the size is different since that's not about shopping, but knowing how to look for a suitable product...

Comment: I was under the impression from photo.stackexchange.com could seek for help here for Apple related stuff. I believe people did ask these kind of questions here before.

Comment: Please flag any hardware shopping questions and we'll close / fix them too... Our [faq] has details on what we consider to be on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to worry - at present, the only MacBook with a physically different keyboard size (in the US) than the rest is the 11 inch Air.

The small Air has a full sized "main keyboard" but the top row of function keys are slightly smaller than the top row of function keys on the rest of the lineup. I would presume that the same holds for international key layouts when they have different enter keys or additional physical keys, but don't know that fact for sure.

The cover you mentioned will fit the new retina MacBooks - both 13" and 15" - as long as the hardware is a US model.

Comment: Thanks @bmike. It almost fits the rMBP keyboard, but there is little not, unlike my MBP.